# Need help in query optimization?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE fa_nls_pd_test ( 
MKT varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
PROD varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRODUCT_LEVEL varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
CAT_NO int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
DYNAMIC_TIME_PERIOD varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRODUCT_LEVEL_DIST varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRODUCT_LEVEL_ACV_TREND varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

How to add index to column "CAT_NO"?
this is update query :

```
update fa_nls_pd_test set DYNAMIC_TIME_PERIOD = NULL where CAT_NO = 0 and period_year = 201502;
```

One transaction cat_no till 11 will update!

Table size = 10.2 GB , rows = 15 millions.

when i run this query ,it takes me more than 1 hour for one period year and how can i optimize query?

Comment: Have you considered also putting an index on the `period_year` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You took that from my mouth. May be he could also try on CAT_NO if that is a frequently accessed item

Comment: Take a look at MySQL's `explain` feature, it helps to decide what indexes make sense: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: Can you tell me how can i add index on period_year and cat_no , I tried but it throws me an error ? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Where is the column PERIOD_YEAR?

Comment: i have not added but it comes like this period_year int(10) default null @etsa

Comment: Can you post what you tried to create the index?

Answer (score 0):

Please check:
column "period_year" does not exist in this table.

If there is period_year column in your table, please try composite indexes:

```
alter table fa_nls_pd_test add unique index(CAT_NO,period_year);
```

composite indexes document : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: I have not typed here ,but its there in my live databases.

Comment: I have update the answer, please try composite indexes

Comment: Hey @Wang Steven , if cat_no is used as subpartition and period_year has used as partition by range, can we still use unique index as you have updated.